# Inheritance of types when using typeof

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstraction, typeof

I'm trying to create a class structure like this:

```
public abstract class ParentClass
{
    protected virtual void BuildQueries()
    {
        var Engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(TopType));
        DataPoints = Engine.ReadFile(ResumeName) as TopType[];
    }

    protected Parent TopType;
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
   protected override Child TopType
}
```

and the types:

```
public abstract class Parent
{
   //some class members here
}

public class Child : Parent
{
   //some class members here
}
```

I think there's an easy answer here, but I'm just too new to C# to figure out what I should be googling. I've tried using generics and I just can't get it right.

I know that without the inheritance I'd write

```
var Engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(Parent));
```

But this is the part of the inheritance that I'm struggling to figure out.

Sorry I failed to mention that FileHelperEngine references the FileHelpers C# library

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but what is really your question?

Comment: My question is, var Engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof([how do I abstract this piece?])). What do I put inside typeof to make it dynamic?

Comment: you could call `GetType()`. That should return the type of the current object

Comment: Your `ChildClass` tries to override a *field*. That is not possible. However a virtual *property* can be overridden.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think @MarcinJuraszek answered the question for me. Sorry the question was so disjointed. I was obviously confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do think you're looking for generics, but I'm not totally sure because your question is not clear...

```
public abstract class ParentClass<T> where T : Parent
{
    protected virtual void BuildQueries()
    {
        var Engine = new FileHelperEngine<T>();
        var r = Engine.ReadFile(ResumeName);
    }

    protected T TopType { get; set; }

    // (...)
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass<Child>
{
    // don't need to override anything, because your property is generic now
    // which means it will be of type `Child` for this class
}

public class FileHelperEngine<T>
    where T : Parent  // this generic constraint might not be necessary
{
    public T[] ReadFile(string name)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'd mucked around with most of these properties before but just didn't know exactly how to put them together. I think this will be what I need. I'm going to test a little before I mark answered.